# Find function that returns last position of searched string

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I need an analog function to find, however I need, that it would return the last position of the searched string, in other words I need opposite function of find

Comment: rfind return the same value as find

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... perhaps [`rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind), for "reverse find"?

Answer (score 0):

If you had been searching the string like this forward:

```
foo.find("bar");
```

To search in reverse use [`rfind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/):

```
foo.rfind("bar");
```

For the given string:

```
string foo{"bar-bar-bar-bar-barbra aaaanne"};
```

`find` will return: `0` and `rfind` will return: `16`

Answer (score -1):

`std::string::rfind` is your saver.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood the question, rather than anything else.

Comment: I'd say then I don't see what's the problem: str.find(sub) + sub.size() or something like that...